Heightfield light shows triangle edges
I'm rendering an heightfield, single directional light, but the triangle edges stand out, even though the normals seem ok. I guess it's a problem with the shader, then, but I can't seem to find it.



This is the snippet of the fragment shader to do lighting calculations:
#version 460
out vec4 FragOutput;

in vec3 v_VertexNormal;
in vec3 v_FragPosition;

struct AmbientLightData
    {
    vec3 Color;
    float Intensity;
    };

struct PointLightData
    {
    vec4 Position;
    vec4 Diffuse, Specular;
    float Intensity;
    float ConstantAttenuation;
    float LinearAttenuation;
    float ExponentialAttenuation;
    };
struct SpotLightData
    {
    vec4 Position;
    vec4 Direction;
    vec4 Diffuse;
    vec4 Specular;
    float Intensity;
    float ConstantAttenuation;
    float LinearAttenuation;
    float ExponentialAttenuation;
    float CutOffAngleCosine;
    float CutOffOuterAngleCosine;
    };
struct DirectionalLightData
    {
    vec4 Direction;
    vec4 Diffuse;
    vec4 Specular;
    float Intensity;
    };
layout ( std140 ) uniform u_LightData
    {
    AmbientLightData AmbientLight;
    PointLightData PointLights[8];
    SpotLightData SpotLights[8];
    DirectionalLightData DirectionalLights[8];
    int PointLightCount, SpotLightCount, DirectionalLightCount;
    } LightData;

void main()
{
vec4 InputDiffuse = vec4(1,1,1,1);
vec3 Normal = normalize(v_VertexNormal);

vec3 TotalDirectionalLightContribution = vec3 ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
for ( int DirectionalLightIndex = 0; DirectionalLightIndex < LightData.DirectionalLightCount; ++DirectionalLightIndex )
    {
    // diffuse
    vec3 NormalizedLightDir = normalize ( -LightData.DirectionalLights[DirectionalLightIndex].Direction.xyz );
    float DiffuseComponent = max ( dot ( Normal, NormalizedLightDir ), 0.0 ); // Calculate dot product on the angle between the two vectors, and make it positive

    // add it all together
    vec3 DiffuseContribution = DiffuseComponent * LightData.DirectionalLights[DirectionalLightIndex].Diffuse.xyz * InputDiffuse.xyz * LightData.DirectionalLights[DirectionalLightIndex].Intensity;
    TotalDirectionalLightContribution += DiffuseContribution;
    }

    // Ambient light is calculated here, so it only adds once to the fragment, instead of once every light
vec3 AmbientLightContribution = LightData.AmbientLight.Color * LightData.AmbientLight.Intensity * InputDiffuse.xyz;

FragOutput = vec4 ( TotalDirectionalLightContribution + AmbientLightContribution, InputDiffuse.a);
}

What is the fault here?
EDIT:
I tried showing the frag normals in the frag shader, and the normals themselves appear "square-y"...
Just changed the end of the shader to
Normal.x+=1.0;
Normal.x/=2.0;
Normal.z+=1.0;
Normal.z/=2.0;
FragOutput = vec4(Normal, 1.0f);


